# scala how to convert future of one type to future of another type

Tags: scala

i have a function which retrieve data from DB and return type of Future[ResponseDTO], then I need to convert it to Future of HttpResponse

my code:

```
val responseDTO = database.getResponseDto(service) => Future[ResponseDTO]

responseDTO.onComplete {
   case Success(responseDTO) => HttpResponse(status = responseDTO.responseCode, entity = responseDTO.responsePayload)
   case Failure(exception) => HttpError("error")
}
```

it wont work

tried this one too, still don't work

```
responseDTO.map(
  dto => EitherT.pure[Future, HttpError](HttpResponse(status = dto.responseCode, entity = dto.responsePayload))
)
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? `onComplete` is for side-effect, you probably want `.map{ dto => HttpResponse(...)}.recover{case NonFatal(e) => HttpError(...)}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to map the future. The `.onComplete` method doesn't transform the future, just adds an handler (useful for side effects)

```
responseDTO.map(dto => HttpResponse(status=dto.responseCode, entity=dto.responsePayload))
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `transform` should give the answer you want:

```
responseDTO.transform {
  case Success(responseDTO) => Success(HttpResponse(status = responseDTO.responseCode, entity = responseDTO.responsePayload))
  case _ => Success(HttpError("error"))
}
```

This will return a successful `Future` whose result type is compatible with both `HttpResponse` and `HttpError`.

If you want to retain the information about success/failure it is best to do this by using the status of the `Future`. In that case your code would use an alternate version of `transform`, like this:

```
case class HttpErrorException(err: HttpError) extends Throwable

responseDTO.transform(
  responseDTO => HttpResponse(status = responseDTO.responseCode, entity = responseDTO.responsePayload),
  _ => HttpErrorException(HttpError("error"))
)
```

You can then use the `Future` methods in the rest of the code to extract the `HttpResponse` or `HttpErrorException` when required.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `.map` for mapping a successful future computation, use `.recover` to map an exception during future computation and `Either` to have a successful/failed result.

```
    val responseDTO: Future[ResponseDTO] = ... 

    val future: Future[Either[HttpError, HttpResponse]] = 
      responseDTO
        .map(d => Right(HttpResponse(status = d.responseCode, entity = d.responsePayload)))
        .recover {
          case t: Throwable => Left(HttpError("error"))
        }
```

if your classes have one superclass, let's say:

```
trait Http

case class HttpResponse(...) extends Http

case class HttpError(...) extends Http
```

you can avoid using `Either`:

```
    val future: Future[Http] =
      responseDTO
        .map(d => HttpResponse(status = d.responseCode, entity = d.responsePayload))
        .recover {
          case t: Throwable => HttpError("error")
        }
```

Comment: A `Future` already carries a success/fail status and an error value, so the `Either` here seems rather redundant.

Comment: @Tim I do not know anything about HttpError and HttpResponse hierarchy. If they are different classes how do you return successful or not value from the Future if they have completely different types? Serializable?

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is map over your previous future of type A to a new future of type B, the onComplete method of the future is side effecting and simply helps to attach callbacks to results and its method signature returns Unit.

Comment: `map` only handles the `Success` case, what about the `Failure` case?

Comment: Map is success Biased .....so if you need to handle the Failure case, I suggest you use the OnComplete Method instead as that will return a try that you can now pattern match on for either a Failure or Success

Comment: `onComplete` does not return `Try`, it returns `Unit`.

Comment: I just checked what i wrote, and it was a mistake, I meant it takes a function Try => Unit